# Бот принимает не то сообщение

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

При выборе действия бот берет последнее сообщение от пользователя, как сделать принятие нового сообщения от пользователя ?

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "USD/UAH")
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ведіть число:") 
    for x in data2:
        k = x["rate"]
        a = message.text 
        try:
            v = float(a)
            c = a*k
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{c}')
        except Exception as x:
                print("error")
```

Comment: Учтите, что после вашего `bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "ведіть число:") ` дальнейший код работает **не** с сообщением, которое пришлет пользователь в ответ на просьбу, а с тем, которое активировало обработчик (в данном случае это `"USD/UAH"`)

Comment: пользователь водит свое число, которое далее умножается и выводится в чат

Comment: https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/step_example.py